# How and when ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction property used?

Tags: powershell, error-reporting

How and when [`ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.errordetails.recommendedaction%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property used? It doesn't appear to get used by default:

```
using namespace System
using namespace System.Management.Automation
$exception = New-Object Exception -ArgumentList "This is the Exception message"
$errorRecord = New-Object ErrorRecord -ArgumentList $exception, "This is the ErrorRecord Message", NotSpecified, $null
$errorDetails = New-Object ErrorDetails -ArgumentList "This is the ErrorDetails message"
$errorRecord.ErrorDetails = $errorDetails
$errorDetails.RecommendedAction = "This is the recommended action"
Write-Error $errorRecord 
 : This is the ErrorDetails message
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

Comment: Powershell `Get-Help 'about_Try_Catch_Finally' -ShowWindow`

Comment: PS displays certain types with a custom format. See `help about_format.ps1xml` for details. In the case of ErrorRecord, RecommendAction is not displayed by default. You can do this: `$errorRecord|select *` or `$errorRecord|ft *` to view all ErrorRecord fields. Or `$errorRecord.recommendedaction` to just access the one field.

Comment: That's nearly, but not quite correct - it is in `$ErrorRecord.ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction`

Answer (score 2):

It is not used by anything within the engine, AFAIK.

But, you can use it for your own purposes!

I have a problem to solve right now where a task can fail because the requested change is already in place - e.g. Add a user account, but the account is already present.

Our coding style requires us to emit a (non-terminating) error, which is in line with behaviour such as New-Item when the item already exists.

But our upstream automation should not move the ticket into a queue for further action - by default, it does so when an error occurs.

In our code, we can just do

`Write-Error 'whatever error msg' -RecommendedAction 'NoFurtherAction'`

and the upstream client can filter ticket actions based on this string in the ErrorDetails:

`$Error[0].ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction -eq 'NoFurtherAction'`